# Multi-threading using Microsoft R rxXYZ() functions

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, microsoft-r

Do all Microsoft R functions (specifically the functions with prefix rx, e.g., rxImport(), rxDataStep(), rxBTrees(), etc.) use multi-threading by default?

If yes, how can I monitor how many cores (or threads) of my local computer are being used while executing these functions? I have seen that while I execute rxBTrees(), in Task Manager, 'Microsoft ML Engine' process starts which consumes ~50-60% of CPU. Does this mean that parallel computing is happening? How to monitor/control the number of threads?

If the answer is 'not all functions use multi-threading', then which functions do/do not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand all rx functions use parallel processing and 4 cores by default (atleast thats the setting in MS Machine Learning server). You can set number of cores with rxOptions(numCoresToUse = 2)